# Returning Boolean value in Groovy function when Maven build fails in shell script

Tags: shell, maven, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I have wrote a Jenkins Pipeline Groovy for executing multiple project maven sonar analysis. The code is working fine but the issue is that sometimes build fails for some projects which I need to track it properly. My **executeMavenSonarBuild** function is given as below

```
def executeMavenSonarBuild(projectName) {
    stage ('Execute Maven Build for '+projectName) 
    {
            sh """ {
                    cd ${projectName}/
                    mvn clean install verify sonar:sonar

                    } || {
                        echo 'Build Failed'
                    }
                """ 
    }
    return true;
}
```

If build fails it prints `echo 'Build Failed'` but how we can return a false Boolean as the return to the function.

Comment: Basically you haven't understood the Maven lifecycle cause you are combining `install verify`. In your case `mvn clean verify` is sufficient cause `install` is not needed...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for correcting that.....how I can return a boolean value as the return to the function based on build failure or success

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the status from the `mvn` call itself..which should look like this:

```
def result = sh ( script: 'mvn ...', returnStatus: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.......what will be the content of `result`...also do you want me to so something like this `def result = sh ( script: 'cd ${projectName}/
                    mvn clean install verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=${projectName} -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.techmahindra.com -Dsonar.projectName=${projectName} -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.test.inclusions=src/test/java/* -Dsonar.sources=src/main -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes 
', returnStatus: true)`

Comment: First I have my doubts about `cd ...` in your script part. Furthermore I assume the configuration of your sonar should already have all these configurations..apart from that the `result` contains `0` if everything is fine not `0` if something is wrong...(bash return code`...

Comment: actually I am calling this function for multiple projects where projectName is the foldername of the maven project where pom.xml resides....so for to enter onto the project folder I do `cd ${projectName}/` then execute mvn clean install ...command